# Why am I getting "failed to flush chunk" when sending container logs to syslogs with fluent-bit?

Tags: syslog, fluent-bit, containerd

Since moving to Containerd as a container runtime instead of Docker, I've been looking for a way to send container logs to syslogs. I have tried numerous configurations with fluent-bit and am always seeing "failed to flush chunk".

config file:

```
"/etc/fluent-bit/fluent-bit.conf" 40L, 897C                                                                                                                                                  30,27         All
[SERVICE]
    Flush 1
    Daemon Off
    Log_Level debug
    Parsers_File /etc/fluent-bit/parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Path /var/log/containers/*.log
    Parser cri
    Tag kube.*
    Mem_Buf_Limit 5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines On

[OUTPUT]
    name                 syslog
    host                 127.0.0.1
    match                *
    port                 514
    mode                 udp
    syslog_format        rfc5424
    syslog_maxsize       2048
    syslog_message_key   message
    syslog_severity_key  severity
    syslog_facility_key  facility
    syslog_hostname_key  hostname
    syslog_appname_key   appname
    syslog_procid_key    procid
    syslog_msgid_key     msgid
    syslog_sd_key        sd

[FILTER]
    Name kubernetes
    Match kube.*
    Merge_Log On
    Merge_Log_Trim On
    Labels Off
    Annotations Off
    K8S-Logging.Parser Off
    K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
```

snippet of fluent-bit logs (with debug enabled):

```
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] inode=1290451 events: IN_MODIFY
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] Send out request to API Server for pods information
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [input chunk] update output instances with new chunk size diff=202
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [task] created task=0x7f0efd03dbd0 id=6 OK
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [task] created task=0x7f0efd03dcb0 id=8 OK
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [input:tail:tail.0] inode=1290451 events: IN_MODIFY
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] Send out request to API Server for pods information
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [input chunk] update output instances with new chunk size diff=184
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [out flush] cb_destroy coro_id=8
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [out flush] cb_destroy coro_id=9
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [retry] new retry created for task_id=6 attempts=1
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '3247533-1667514444.161129247.flb', retry in 9 seconds: task_id=6, input=tail.0 > output=syslog.0 (out_id=0)
Nov 03 22:27:24 apicdev1224 fluent-bit[3247533]: [2022/11/03 22:27:24] [debug] [retry] new retry created for task_id=8 attempts=1
```

fluent-bit version: 2.0.3
containerd version: 1.5.11-1

Comment: did you test the output sending it to stdout?